# Binary search tree compute the coordinate of nodes

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree, traversal

I need to get the x,y coords of all nodes, for example:

```
        10
   8        15
7    9     13
```

X: the number of nodes visited already before visiting the node with in-order traversal

Y: the depth of the node from the root

e.g. for node 15, x=5 (before 15: already visited 7, 8, 9, 10, 13), y=1(second level)

There is no parent pointer for the tree

```
int inorder(Node *node, int x) {

    if (node->left)
        x = inorder(node->left, x);
    x++;
    if (node->right)
        inorder(node->right, x);
    return x;
}



int x0(Node *node) {
    return inorder(node, -1);
}



int findY(Node *node, Node *from) {

    if (node == from)
        return 0;
    else if (node->item < from->item)
        return findY(node, from->left) + 1;
    else
        return findY(node, from->right) + 1;
}

int y0(Node *node) {
    return findY(node, theRoot);
}
```

result: x is wrong and y is correct

print:

```
void printCoord() {

    queue<Node*> q;
    q.push(theRoot);


    int curLevel = 0;
    while (q.size() > 0) {
        Node *n = q.front();
        q.pop();

        int x = x0(n);
        int y = y0(n);

        if (y > curLevel) {
            curLevel = y;
            cout << endl;
        }

        cout << n->item << "(" << x << "," << y <<")";
        if (n->left)
            q.push(n->left);
        if (n->right)
            q.push(n->right);
    }

}







AvlTree tree;
tree.insertBalance(10);
tree.insertBalance(8);
tree.insertBalance(15);
tree.insertBalance(7);
tree.insertBalance(9);
tree.insertBalance(13);


tree.printCoord();
```

Result:

```
10(2,0)
8(1,1)15(1,1)
7(0,2)9(0,2)13(0,2)
```

I have tried (which I don't think is correct because the right subtree traversal is not counted for the node)

```
int inorder(Node *node, int x) {

    if (node->left)
        x = inorder(node->left, x);
    x++;
    if (node->right)
        x = inorder(node->right, x);
    return x;
}
```

and the result is

```
10(5,0)
8(2,1)15(1,1)
7(0,2)9(0,2)13(0,2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// your inorder function is not correct
bool inorder(Node* node, int* x, Node* root) {
    if (root==NULL)
        return false;

    if (inorder(node, x, root->left))
        return true;

    if (node==root) //inorder property here
        return true;

    (*x)++;

    if (inorder(node, x, root->right))
        return true;

    return false;

}

int x0(Node *node) {
    int x=0;
    if (inorder(node, &x, theRoot)) //you did't pass root here
        return x;
    else //not found
        return -1;

}
```

Points:

1. You didn't pass the root and checked with the query node. That's not correct. You need to search the tree from the root.
2. For any inorder property, basic idea is you go left, do what you want, then go right. But this may vary according to your problem.
3. If the query node is found, no further `inorder` call takes place. It returns all the way to `x0` with `x` containing the desired value.

Comment: infinite loop. do you mean in if (order(node->left, x, root)) ?

Comment: Sorry for that! Mixed up yours and my code. Edited.

Comment: and i would love to know why my original function doesn't work. thank you

Comment: @OMGPOP: Your original function took the node to get x for as the root of a subtree, but you're looking for the overall index, starting at `theRoot`. How can you account for nodes 7 to 10 when you start at node 15 and you can only recuse downwards? Your `inorder` needs to have two node pointers: the node you're looking at with `theRoot` as initial value and the node whose x you're going to find.

Comment: I'm afraid that the code is still quite confusing to me. is it possible to return int (the current progress of traversal)

Comment: @OMGPOP What do you not understand?

Comment: is it possible not to use pass by reference (e.g. when using java etc).

Comment: @OMGPOP It is passed by value. The value of the pointer is passed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this:

```
if (node->right)
    inorder(node->right, x);
```

is supposed to be:

```
if (node->right)
    x = inorder(node->right, x);
```

Unless you really only mean to count the left-side nodes.

Comment: why? the result of right sub tree is not supposed to be counted for the node